# Build error after upgrading to Expo SDK 47(TypeError,Invariant Violation)

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo, invariants

## Summary:

I upgrade the Enatega Customer app from SDK 44 to 47. I expect the app is be built successfully.

## Managed or bare workflow?

Expo Managed Project

## What platform(s) does this occur on?

Both Android and iOS.

## SDK Version

expo '47.0.0'

## **

## Reproducible demo or steps to reproduce from a blank project**

I upgraded my SDK from 44 to 47, using npm i -g expo-cli and expo upgrade, and make a expo publish and npx expo start as are made others many times.

## **

## The error occurs in node_modules(TypeError,Invariant Violation)**

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style') at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:25:19 in errorHandler at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:30:24 in at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:237:40 in guardedLoadModule at http://10.97.28.19:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global code`

`Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter. A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native. at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:25:19 in errorHandler at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:30:24 in at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError`

`Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter. A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native. at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:17 in reportException at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:39 in handleError at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:25:19 in errorHandler at node_modules/expo/build/errors/ExpoErrorManager.js:30:24 in at node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError`

How to solve this issue?

## My Package.json File

```
{
  "name": "enatega-full-app",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest",
    "format": "prettier --write '**/*.js'",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .js --fix",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "npm run format",
      "npm run lint:fix"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.3.1",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.5.1",
    "apollo-cache-persist": "^0.1.1",
    "apollo-client": "^2.5.1",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.17",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.14",
    "apollo-link-state": "^0.4.2",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^10.0.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-analytics-amplitude": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-app-auth": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-localization": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-apollo": "^2.5.8",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.23",
    "react-native-flatlist-slider": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-timeline-flatlist": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "validate.js": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "9.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "prettier-config-standard": "^1.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|expo|@expo|apollo-boost|apollo-cache-inmemory|apollo-client|apollo-link-context|apollo-link-http|apollo-link-state|apollo-upload-client|graphql|graphql-tag|react-apollo|react-native-animatable|react-native-material-buttons|react-native-material-ripple|react-native-material-textfield|react-native-ratings|react-native-swiper-flatlist|react-native-timeline-listview|react-navigation|validate.js)/)"
    ]
  },
  "private": true

}
```

## GitHub:

**Only target the Customer App inside this repo**
https://github.com/Ninjas-Code-official/Enatega-Restaurant-Solution.git